# Huge algorithm taking up space

Tags: floats, algorithm2e

I have an algorithm description that takes up an entire image. However, when compiling my latex document, the algorithm and subsequent images following it are pushed to the end of the document. I don't mind the size of the algorithm, but I would like to put in the page immediately preceding the page having the description or after. Any suggestions? I have tried [!h] as suggested in some other related post. But it does not help.

Comment: Have you tried including the `[p]` option?

Comment: `[!h]` is almost certain to take a float to the end of the document Its main effect is to not allow latex to put it at the top, bottom of a text page, or on a float page, which gives it rather few places it can go.

Comment: @CharlesStaats The [p] option works. Thanks for your help. I was not aware of such an option.

Comment: @AnirudhKaushik `p` is allowed by default so simpler (and usually better) is not to use the option at all

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.